# why height:auto doesnt work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 questions :

1. why element `#post` doesn't stretch enough to cover the image ? although i set `height:auto` .
2. why this problem will solve with `overflow:hidden` ? as i know `overflow:hidden` is used when a element go out from its parent and it hide out part . in my example it doesn't hide it . it stretches parent element to cover image. why?

excuse me for bad english.
if it possible explain with simply english words . 
many thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="posts">
<div id="new-posts">
    <img src="https://weneedfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Daisy-Flower-
3.jpg">
    <p>here is ccontent of post . here is ccontent of post .
        here is ccontent of post . here is ccontent of post .
        here is ccontent of post . here is ccontent of post . </p>
</div>
```

css :

```
#posts {
border: 1px solid;
/* overflow: hidden; */
height: auto;
}

#new-posts img{
float: left;
margin: 10px;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

jsfiddle:

with overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/hamed98/ez66sgwt/

without overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/hamed98/sL25m9mx/

Answer (score 2):

1. This is because the image has a `float` property. Floating elements by design may cross the boundaries of the block element, including their parent block (why are they designed that way, is well explained [in this article](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/)). That is why the auto height of the container is determined only by its non-floating contents (text paragraph).
2. By setting the container `overflow` other than `visible`, you make the container the new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) (as a side effect of this property). Unlike usual blocks, blocks with the new block formatting context don't let floats cross their boundaries, so they always contain their nested floats.

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute

```
 #posts {
border: 1px solid;
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Does this answer any of the OPs questions?